# Android - Gradle - Compare flavors directories

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

In my Android project, I have multiples variants (flavors) with different resources files into.

I want to be able to compare two of those flavors directories, to check if at least, number of files are equals and list the difference.

For now, I only able to count difference with this method :

```
    def totoResFiles = []
    file("./src/toto/").eachFileRecurse { file ->
        totoResFiles << file
    }
    def tataResFiles = []
    file("./src/tata/").eachFileRecurse { file ->
        tataResFiles << file
    }

    if (totoResFiles.size() != tataResFiles.size()) {
        throw new GradleException('Toto res files (' + totoResFiles.size() + ') are not equals to Tata res files (' + tataResFiles.size() + ')')
    }
```

I put this code in my build.gradle file in the `preBuild.doFirst` closure.

How can I list difference between two directories ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Get the filenames to the list and compare both.

Comment: It is possible to diff two list ? With intersect or something else ?
I'm not confident with groovy...